# Why use transpose in finding if a subset is also a subspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I had a homework question in my linear algebra course that asks: Are the symmetric 3x3 matrices a subspace of R^3x3?

The answer goes on to prove that if A^t = A and B^t = B then (A+B)^t = A^t + B^t = A + B so it is closed under addition. (it is also closed under multiplication).

What I don't understand is why are they using transpose to prove this? I don't see the connection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix $A$ is symmetric if $A^T = A$. A vector space must be closed under addition so if symmetric matrices are a subspace, the sum of two symmetric matrices must be symmetric. To prove that this is the case, we consider the sum of two symmetric matrices, say $C = A + B$ with $A$ and $B$ symmetric, and we want to show that $C$ is symmetric - or equivalently, that $C^T = C$. The computation in your question confirms that $C$ satisfies that relation and thus is symmetric.